# Issue using NSError in a convenience init

Tags: swift, swift2

The error said

> Constant ‘err’ used before being initialized

and

> Constant ‘err’ capture by a closure before initialized

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
    public convenience init(nsurl:NSURL) {
    var enc:NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
    let err:NSError?
    let str =
    String(try! NSString(
        contentsOfURL:nsurl, usedEncoding:&enc))
       //the code below got error
    if err != nil { self.init(err!) }
    else { self.init(string:str) }
}
```

Comment: You're testing to see if `err` is not nil before you ever assign a value to the constant. Why does this check exist? What do you think the use of `err` in this initializer is?

Comment: So what am i supposed to change?

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet, I don't see where `err` would be populated with an actual error message?

You create the `err` variable then you don't use it, so it will always be nil.

It would be better to use `try` inside Do-Catch.

Something like this:

```
public convenience init(nsurl:NSURL) {
    var enc:NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
    do {
        let str = try String(contentsOfURL:nsurl, usedEncoding:&enc)
        self.init(string:str)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        self.init(string: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```